# Swift: How to avoid "Code after 'throw' will never be executed" warning

Tags: swift

Is there any workaround for this warning? `perform()` need a `return` statement to infer the opaque return type, but the `return` statement after the `throw` statement raises the warning "will never be executed". Swift 5

```
import AppIntents

struct MyIntent: AppIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Title"
    
    @MainActor
    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ReturnsValue<Date> {
#if os(watchOS)
        // code for watchOS
#elseif os(iOS)
        throw MyError.notAvailable // -> Error "Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type"
#endif
        return .result(value: .now) // -> Warning "Code after 'throw' will never be executed"
    }
}

enum MyError: Error {
    case notAvailable
}
```

Comment: You never return anything, so it's not possible to infer the opaque return type

Comment: `throw` is allowed, but the way you are using it doesn't satisfy the method signature.  There needs to be a "success" case where something is returned to allow return type to be inferred.  Uncommenting the return statement would work, although, as the warning says, it will never be reached because your throw an error and exit first.

Comment: Be aware that `throw`ing an error exits the current scope immediately.

Comment: @flanker How to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your function:

```
func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ReturnsValue<Date> {
#if os(watchOS)
    // code for watchOS
#elseif os(iOS)
    throw MyError.notAvailable
#endif
    return .result(value: .now)
}
```

is that under iOS, it looks like this:

```
func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ReturnsValue<Date> {
    throw MyError.notAvailable

    return .result(value: .now)
}
```

Nothing after the `throw` can happen which is why you get the warning "Code after 'throw' will never be executed".

So you are in a bind here. If you remove the `return` you get the error "Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type" when building for iOS. But with the `return` you get the warning.

Normally a `throw` only happens under some condition. But you want the `throws` to happen for all conditions when building for iOS.

The following is a trick to make the compiler happy under iOS. At runtime this `if` statement will always be true and always `throw`. But the compiler can't determine that so it thinks the `return` can be reached.

```
func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult & ReturnsValue<Date> {
#if os(watchOS)
    // code for watchOS
#elseif os(iOS)
    if ("x" == "x") {
        throw MyError.notAvailable
    }
#endif
    return .result(value: .now)
}
```

Oddly if you use `if (true == true)` or `if (1 == 1)`, for example, the compiler still complains about the `return` being unreachable. It only seems to get confused enough for your needs if you use two strings.

Comment: Thanks! I found `if "".isEmpty` is enough for the compiler.